# Why does creating token result in "parent token lookup failed"

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have an issue with creating tokens for `hashicorp-vault` using salt.

Create token:

```
$ curl --header "X-Vault-Token: f3821c23-4558-72db-8739-bbf7ac4b90d1" \
       --request POST \
       --data @create_token.json \
       http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/token/create

{"request_id":"72ba8117-fcb8-506d-f1c4-fe0e5e0f5cbf","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":0,"data":null,"wrap_info":null,"warnings":["Policy \"saltstack/minion/myhost\" does not exist"],"auth":{"client_token":"96bfd0f2-a10a-d966-2d46-3f803fb1d995","accessor":"8a0a296f-d19a-e01c-4782-0fbab06a6ebe","policies":["default","saltstack/minion/admin.p13","saltstack/minions"],"metadata":null,"lease_duration":2764800,"renewable":true,"entity_id":""}}
```

Create a child token using `client_token` of the first operation.

```
$ curl --header "X-Vault-Token: 96bfd0f2-a10a-d966-2d46-3f803fb1d995" \
       --request POST \
       --data @test.json \
       http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/token/create

{"errors":["parent token lookup failed"]}
```

Used payloads:

File `create_token.json`

```
{"policies": ["saltstack/minion/myhost", "saltstack/minions"], "num_uses":1}
```

File `test.json`

```
{"num_uses": 0, "policies": ["default", "myapp"], "ttl": "1h", "no_parent": true, "renewable": true, "metadata": {"user": "root"}}
```

Comment: The "no_parent" option can be called only by root token. Does "96bfd0f2-a10a-d966-2d46-3f803fb1d995" has root privileges on auth/token/create?

Comment: you are not actually using salt here if you are running `curl` commands

Comment: Any luck finfing out how to do this without custom runner? All intermediate tokens generated from main salt token have num_uses 1 and throw parent token lookup failure.

Answer (score 1):

The orphan tokens can only be created:

- Via the `auth/token/create-orphan` endpoint
- By having `sudo` capability or **root policy** when accessing `auth/token/create` and **setting the orphan parameter to true**

Which implies that your initial token doesn't have root policy associated with it. as you can see below in your policies list,

```
"policies":["default","saltstack/minion/admin.p13","saltstack/minions"],"metadata":null,"lease_duration":2764800,"renewable":true,"entity_id":""}}
```

Beside,

If you are using salt, then your Master token must have privileges to create new tokens in minions, which you can then create using `vault.write_secret`

Comment: It turned out that `runners/vault.py` tokens get created with `num_uses=1`. With this temporary token it is possible to create another token, but vault will complain that token doesn't have a parent. I created my own runner to create tokens on master and distribute them using a state module.